# How to combine multiple display conditions in Perl/HTML in a multiple choice survey

Tags: html, perl, survey

I am designing a survey and it is written in HTML/CSS and uses Perl logic.

I have a screening question (q1) at the start which has three answers:
A car crash (broad_screen_1)
A diagnosis of diabetes (broad_screen_2)
A diagnosis of cancer (broad_screen_3)
A diagnosis of heart disease (broad_screen_4)
None of the above (broad_screen_5)

In the code, the answer is recorded as (1='not selected', 2='selected'). It is multiple choice.

I would like a screen-out section of the survey to be displayed if:
broad_screen_3 is not selected ($broad_screen_3 !=2) or if broad_screen_5 is selected ($broad_screen_5 = 2).

Each display condition works, but not together. How do I combine the two? I have tried adding OR as boolean operators, also added commas separating the two arguments but this does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you allow multiple choices, the answer itself is not a variable that equals to 3. Depending on your code it might be list like [2,3], a dictionary like {2:true, 3:true} or a string that is imploded with a comma like "2,3". So you cant verify whether the answer 3 equals to someone's answer if there is multiple.

The solution of it: You can simply check whether the 3 is in the given answer or not. We could provide mode 'code specific' answer but you did not provide the code itself. So this is the philosophy of it. :)

Comment: Thanks for this insight. Based on the survey building site - it mentions strings. Is there any way I am able to try a few different things to check if they work? If not, is there a way to use a quote for example ($q1="Example wording") or something similar? 
Thanks again in advance!

Comment: If I don't know something and I'm trying to understand, the best method for me is always to print out what I don't know. So I highly recommend you to print the output of answer while testing your code. With this way, you can easily see how changing answers affect your final variable. Try some vairations and eventually you'll figure it out.

Comment: Hi JamalThaBoss - please see my clarification here: 

In the code, the answer is recorded as (1='not selected', 2='selected'). 

It is multiple choice, with each answer recorded in the code as broad_screen_1, broad_screen_2 etc. up to 5. 

I would like a screen-out section of the survey to be displayed if: broad_screen_3 is not selected ($broad_screen_3 !=2) or if broad_screen_5 is selected ($broad_screen_5 = 2).

Each display condition works, on its own. How do I combine the two? I have tried adding OR, also added commas separating the two arguments but this does not work. Thanks!